# What is the name of this element? For the elections

Tags: website-design, design-patterns, dynamic-ui

I know it goes with the family of Information Visualisation Charts, but do we call this specifically.
[image: 2016 U.S.Elections]

Answer (score 5):

It's a "100% stacked bar chart", see examples [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=100%25%20stacked%20bar%20chart&t=canonical&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images). Only that in your case you have only one bar instead of many.

Here's a bit more on its characteristics that determine how the name is composed:

- 100% because it includes all possible components and they add up to 100%
- stacked, because they all show up on top of each other (as a single line) rather than side by side as conventional bar charts
- it is also horizontal (left implicit above)
- there's also an implicit reference line pointing at the middle
- and clearly it falls into the wider category of bar charts

Comment: +1 really nice answer. I assume you do a bit of infographic/datavis design yourself? :)

Comment: @MichaelLai, kind of. I use a lot of [exploratory data analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis) in my research. More often than not I have to present publicly not only the results, but also how I arrived at them.